# Compilador SCOUT não gera arquivo css

Tags: css, sass, compiladores

Boa tarde, estou utilizando o compilador SCOUT para trabalhar com arquivos scss e sass, porém de ontem para hoje ele não está mais gerando arquivos css, ele está configurado corretamente para as pastas do projeto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver o arquivo está sendo modificado, porém não é gerado o arquivo css.

Comment: A mensagem de erro diz que tem css inválido, você conferiu as linhas?

Comment: Eu alterei o código somente para conferir se alterava no scouter também. O código é *{ border: 0;}

Comment: Que azar cara, espero que alguém te ajude, aqui em casa o scout nem instalou.